# C - Make variable INT as Char * for strcat

Tags: c, pointers, char, strcat

I'm trying to make a char * with the char representing an integer.
So I have this so far

```
int x;
for(x=0;x<12;x++){
    cp->name=strcat(tp->name, (char *)x);
}
```

name is char*
The problem is the x portion. I get segmentation fault and I'm assuming it's because it can't access the address the contents of x and cast it as char *

any tips on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

By casting `x` to a `char *`, you're telling the compiler, "I know what I'm doing. Treat `x` as an address and pass it to `strcat`"

Because `x` contains an integer between 0 and 12, `strcat` is trying to access a char array at address at that number. Because that address in memory most likely doesn't belong to you, you're getting a segfault.

You'll need `sprintf` or `snprintf` for getting a string representation of the integer.

For example:

```
int x;
for(x=0;x<12;x++){
    char buffer[16];
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d", x);
    cp->name=strcat(tp->name, buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly convert the number in `x` into a string (=array of `chars`). You can't do this by a mere type cast.

Using `sprintf()` is probably the easiest way:

```
int x;
for (x = 0; x < 12; x++)
    sprintf(tp->name + strlen(tp->name), "%d", x);
```

Needless to say, `tp->name` must have enough space in it and it must be `'\0'`-terminated before you do the above.

Comment: note that this modifies `tp->name` and will produce something like "tp123456789101112" if `tp->name` initially contains "tp".

Comment: @LieRyan Well, that's what the OP is apparently asking for and it may be what's needed, we don't know.

Answer (score 0):

In C, you can use `sprintf(str,"%d",x)`; or in C++ stringstream `std::ostringstream oss; oss << tp->name << x;`. If you have no qualms with using non-standard function, you can also use non-standard [itoa()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/) function.